# what is best practice to return single value data with record set of data

Tags: sql

I am obtaining some single value data like

```
 Number Users in system
 Number of Books in system
 Number books checked out by a particular user
```

Then for any user, I will also need to return a record set:

```
 ISBN of each book checked out for a month
```

In other words this is what I want to receive back

```
 26  ( number users in system )
 256 ( number books in system )
 19  ( books checked out by user )
 12345454, 1235544, 1243433, 1345993, 3349934  ( List of ISBNs for user for month )
```

What is the best practice to return the above data to a client application?

A little more clarification, what SQL statement would return this information?

I got the "Select ISBN from Records where user = 'user'  -- that one I get.. the other values are what are throwing me...?  Is it as simple as "select count(*) from users" for number of users? (etc)

in other words, would the stored proc be something like this:

```
 Select count(*) from users
 Select count(*) from books
 Select count(*) from checkouts where user = 'user'
 Select ISBN from Records where user = 'user'
```

Is this the type of stored procedure that I need to write?

Thanks

Comment: `ISBN for each book...` is **not** a single-value return.

Comment: Exactly, the results for ISBN would be a set, like 123123, 123124, 1232431, 123141, 1231234

Comment: So **what** is your question then?

Comment: I think you're very close to your answer. It looks like you just need to wrap the multiple queries in a Create Stored Procedure statement.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't think it would be that easy ... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Procedures in Sql Server can return multiple result sets. You can call one stored proc with your inputs, and get back the results of multiple queries in one go. HOWEVER, you need to code for receiving multiple result sets or pick a stored proc handling library that can deal with multiple result sets.

Steve G.

Comment: Steve G.  -- thanks... I have written lots of client code that handles multiple results sets... what I would like to know is HOW those multiple sets got generated on the SQL side... in particular, the "single" value data that I mention in the question.

Comment: It's easier than you might think. In the stored proc, simply execute multiple queries to get multiple result sets. For the single value you can have one query (first or last to make your life easier) generate that single value. On the client side you can simply expect the query that's returning your single value to have one row of data with one column.